# Should the testing data be uniquely distinct and come from different source/dataset than the training data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am building an audio classification system using CNN. My dataset consists of different audio I have recorded and spliced to equal time lengths. Like with any other common ML or DL tasks, I am to split my dataset into training and testing data and evaluate my model. However, my professor said that the testing data must NOT come from the same environment/source as the training data. Since I recorded all my audio samples and spliced them and split them as training and testing data, they essentially come from the same environment. He basically argues that testing data essentially has to be "in the wild".

However, my opinion on this is that as long as my model does not train and does not take the testing data as its input during model fitting, the testing data is considered 'unseeen' and 'in the wild'. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use your algorithm to classify out in the wild, then you will be interested in OOS performance on real-world data. The hope is that the lessons from the synthetic data generalize beyond it.

This is a higher bar than data you did not train on, but the right one for deciding whether to unleash your algo on the world.